# Bootstrap 4 carousel caption vertical align

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to center my carousel caption on bootstrap 4 but I can't find a way to do it. Nothing works for me. I tried adding `align-items-center` `justify-content-center` `text-center` adding on my `carousel-item` or `carousel-caption` but nothing works.

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 100%
}

.carousel-item:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.carousel-item {
  height: 100vh;
}

.carousel-image-1 {
  background: url('../images/miami1.jpeg');
  background-size: cover;
}

.carousel-image-2 {
  background: url('../images/miami2.jpeg');
  background-size: cover;
}

.carousel-image-3 {
  background: url('../images/miami3.jpeg');
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item carousel-image-1">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption text-right mb-5">
                        <h1 class="display-3">Sveiki</h1>
                        <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor enim ex
                            exercitationem laboriosam nihil numquam tempora, vitae voluptates. Dolores, maxime!</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item carousel-image-2 active">
                    <div class="carousel-caption mb-5">
                        <h1 class="display-3">Miami</h1>
                        <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor enim ex
                            exercitationem laboriosam nihil.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Sužinok daugiau</a>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item carousel-image-3">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption text-right mb-5">
                        <h1 class="display-3">Sveiki</h1>
                        <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor enim ex
                            exercitationem laboriosam nihil numquam tempora, vitae voluptates. Dolores, maxime!</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev" class="carousel-control-prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
        </a>
        <a href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next" class="carousel-control-next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Edited. I added my html code

Comment: Is there a reason for the container inside the items?

Comment: Can you provide a complete snippet of code that will reproduce your problem? When I use your code as-is, nothing is displayed.

Comment: @ZimSystem not really. I just added it out of habit i guess.

Comment: @Blazemonger I added my css also. You need images to work I guess so add just random ones. Maybe it will work now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TranslateY, and overriding the Bootstrap bottom position should work. You also want to remove the containers.

```
.carousel-caption {
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  bottom: 0;
  top: 50%;
}
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/ziV9Qvxms8